# autoplay video in react iframe after user interactive ( ios - not working )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video, iframe, autoplay

I have a **react app** as a widget in the iframe tag at **basic (html-css-js) project**.

On the ( basic project ) I've got a video that ( autopay & muted ), when the user will click anywhere on the video my action is to hide that video and show the iframe tag ( react app ),

The ( react app ) has the first component as a video with **autoplay** & **not muted**.

My problem is, on the web it works, but on the iPhone ( ios ) doesn't.

- Note: The user is already interactive since he clicks on the video on ( basic project )

Any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: check the note about IOS [on CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/mdn-html_elements_video_autoplay)

Comment: Thanks, @Randy Casburn, but there is an example, I am not sure how it works, [link](https://newtieshotsauce.com/)  click on the gif when the page is completed loaded  and see the video!

Comment: that video has no audio - if you read the note in the link, it clearly says it works if the video has no audio.

Comment: Yeah the clear, but when you click on the video/gif , then you will see a video/now video that has audio.

Comment: @Randy Casburn, there are two videos/gif on the previous link, the one on the bottom right is what I mean, it looks like a separated widget

Comment: Custom play control overlaid onto the non-audio video that seems invisible but provides the "play" interaction necessary? Just a guess.